# Как настроить jsdoc, чтобы в наследуемых классах отображались только переопределённые методы

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

```js
/**
 * @class
 * @name Shape
 */
export default class Shape {
  getType() {
    return 'shape';
  }

  getName() {
    return 'Shape';
  }
}
```

```js
/**
 * @class
 * @name Circle
 * @extends Shape
 */
export default class Circle {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  /**
   * @name Circle#getName
   * @override Shape
   */
  getName() {
    return 'Circle';
  }
}
```

`jsdoc.json:`

```json
{
  "tags": {
    "allowUnknownTags": false
  },
  "source": {
    "include": "resources/js/classes/shapes",
    "includePattern": "\\.js$",
    "excludePattern": "(node_modules/|docs)"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "plugins/markdown"
  ],
  "opts": {
    "template": "node_modules/docdash",
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "destination": "../jsapidoc",
    "recurse": true,
    "verbose": true
  },
  "templates": {
    "cleverLinks": false,
    "monospaceLinks": false
  }
}
```

Версия: `"jsdoc": "^3.6.6"`

При такой документации у меня все методы отображаются и в классе `Shape` и в классе `Circle`. Как решить проблему?

Comment: скажите тогда, что значит ваше "все методы отображаются" и зачем вы хотите скрыть какие-то методы?

Comment: @ThisMan Есть метод, который не переопределяется во всех наследниках. Но в некоторых он переопределяется. Так вот зачем мне в документации видеть  у каждого наследника одинаковые методы с родителем? А вот если в каком-то из наследников был переопределён метод, то его необходимо отобразить.  И сказать, данный метод переопределён. Так как он отличается от одноимённого метода родителя.

Comment: попробуйте вот такое https://jsdoc.app/tags-override.html

Comment: @ThisMan подправил вопрос